# Is it possible to disable VS Code Golang BrokenImport errors for one line?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm developing/running a go application inside a container. Inside the container, we have a version of go compiled with `GOEXPERIMENT=BORINGCRPYTO`.

In VS Code, I have a single line showing a red underlined `BrokenImport` error, for

```golang
    _ "crypto/tls/fipsonly"
```

This is not a true `BrokenImport`, but it's because I didn't compile golang with that experiment on the host. Will every developer need to compile golang with this flag to get rid of these editor errors or is there a way in VS Code to disable this specific error or this specific line?

I was hoping for something along the lines of:

```
//ignore-next-line: BrokenImport
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to find a way to directly disable a single line, I was able to at least get the editor to understand the code by configuring VS Code to pass the `GOEXPERIMENT=boringcrypto` environment variable to the `gopls` language server.

To do so, add the following to your vs code settings.json:

```
"go.toolsEnvVars": {
    "GOEXPERIMENT": "boringcrypto"
  }
```

This can be found by going to the settings and navigating to Go: Tools Env Vars > Edit in settings.json

[image]